# Error Operator '<>' is not defined for types 'System.Diagnostics.Process' and 'System.Diagnostics.Process'

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors

Error: Operator `<>` is not defined for types `System.Diagnostics.Process` and `System.Diagnostics.Process`.

Function With error

```vb
Public Shared Function PornesteJocul() As Boolean
    Return Process.GetProcessesByName(DatePatch.BinaryName).FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.MainModule.FileName.StartsWith("")) <> CType(Nothing, Process)
End Function
```

Thanks.

Comment: `return Process.GetProcessesByName(DatePatch.BinaryName).FirstOrDefault(Function(p) String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainModule?.FileName)) isnot nothing`. I suggest you do this in a `Try/Catch/Finally` block. You can also use `.All()`, verifying the opposite condition. Or `Count() > 0 etc.`. The `FirstOrDefault()` thing can be *confusing*.

Comment: Why are you looking for a file name that starts with an empty `String`? That's not your real code, is it?

Comment: Do you realize that `StartsWith("")` will always return True for any string value other than null (for which you will receive a null reference exception)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare something to `Nothing` then just compare it. There's no need to cast `Nothing` as a specific type. Also, you use `=` and `<>` only for value equality. That means for value types (structures) and for some very few reference types where value equality makes sense, e.g. for `Strings` where you care that two `String` objects contain the same characters and not whether two references refer to one `String` object. For reference equality you use `Is` and `IsNot`:

```
Return Process.GetProcessesByName(DatePatch.BinaryName).FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.MainModule.FileName.StartsWith("")) IsNot Nothing
```

If what you actually care about is whether or not there is a match though, rather than what that match is, you don't need a comparison:

```
Return Process.GetProcessesByName(DatePatch.BinaryName).Any(Function(p) p.MainModule.FileName.StartsWith(""))
```